# TF 2.0 print tensor values

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm learning the newest release of Tensorflow (2.0) and I have tried to run a simple code to slice a matrix.
Using the decorator @tf.function I made the following class:

```
class Data:
def __init__(self):
    pass

def back_to_zero(self, input):
    time = tf.slice(input, [0,0], [-1,1])
    new_time = time - time[0][0]
    return new_time

@tf.function
def load_data(self, inputs):
    new_x = self.back_to_zero(inputs)
    print(new_x)
```

So, when run the code using a numpy matrix, I can't retrieve the numbers.

```
time = np.linspace(0,10,20)
magntiudes = np.random.normal(0,1,size=20)
x = np.vstack([time, magntiudes]).T


d = Data()
d.load_data(x)
```

Output:

```
Tensor("sub:0", shape=(20, 1), dtype=float64)
```

I need to get this tensor in a numpy format, but TF 2.0 has not the class tf.Session to use run() or eval() methods.

Thanks for any help that you can offer me!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside the graph indicated by the decorator `@tf.function`, you can use [tf.print](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/print) to print the values of your tensor.

```
tf.print(new_x)
```

Here is how the code can be rewritten

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def back_to_zero(self, input):
        time = tf.slice(input, [0,0], [-1,1])
        new_time = time - time[0][0]
        return new_time

    @tf.function
    def load_data(self, inputs):
        new_x = self.back_to_zero(inputs)
        tf.print(new_x) # print inside the graph context
        return new_x

time = np.linspace(0,10,20)
magntiudes = np.random.normal(0,1,size=20)
x = np.vstack([time, magntiudes]).T

d = Data()
data = d.load_data(x)
print(data) # print outside the graph context
```

the tensor type outside the `tf.decorator` context is of type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor`. To convert it to a numpy array, you can use `data.numpy()`

Comment: Hi edkeveked. I added the tf.print statement inside the tf.function  but It doesn't show anything.

Comment: The tf.print statement only returns `<tf.Operation 'PrintV2_3' type=PrintV2>` :-( What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you can't get the values of the tensor directly inside the graph. So you either do as @edkeveked suggested using `tf.print` or change your code as follows:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def back_to_zero(self, input):
        time = tf.slice(input, [0,0], [-1,1])
        new_time = time - time[0][0]

        return new_time

    @tf.function
    def load_data(self, inputs):
        new_x = self.back_to_zero(inputs)

        return new_x

time = np.linspace(0,10,20)
magntiudes = np.random.normal(0,1,size=20)
x = np.vstack([time, magntiudes]).T

d = Data()
data = d.load_data(x)
print(data.numpy())
```

Comment: Gorjan, thank for your answer. Your solution show me the following error:  'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'